# Domain construction Haskell

Tags: haskell, domain-modelling

I have a data type :

```
data Tree e = Node e (Tree e) (Tree e) | Empty deriving (Show)

type Forest e = [Tree e]

data Animal = Squirrel | None deriving (Show)
```

and the graphical representation of **Forest Int** is :

[image]

The last element is bottom. Then in second last row, it can be empty. But i didn't understand what `⊥:⊥` mean. Is it the constructor for list? like this `5:[]`? Then in 3rd row, why `[]` is missing in `Empty:⊥`.

Can anyone please explain me what I am understanding wrong here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `_|_ : _|_` is the constructor for lists `:`, applies to an undefined list element and undefined list tail. This is the value, for instance, associated to the Haskell program

```
let list = list
    elem = elem
in elem : list
```

Similarly, `Empty : _|_` is the value associated to

```
let list = list
in Empty : list
```

There's no `[]` here because the tail of the list fails to terminate (converge) because of the infinite recursion, so its value is undefined (`_|_`).

In the domain ordering, we have the increasing sequence

```
_|_
Empty : _|_
Empty : Empty : _|_
Empty : Empty : Empty : _|_
...
```

having limit (AKA lub or supremum) the infinite list repeating `Empty` forever.

The value

```
_|_ : _|_ : _|_
```

is the one associated to

```
let list = list
    elem = elem
in elem : elem : list
```

By comparison,

```
_|_ : _|_ : []
```

is the value of

```
let elem = elem
in elem : elem : []
```

Note that the above allows the length to be computed, since the list has a definite end. Taking its `length` will produce 2, since there's no need to evaluate the list elements, so no bottom is forced.

Comment: and what will be the case for _|_ : ( _|_ : _|_ ). 3rd row, first element from right?

Comment: so you mean, there are 2 elements in list and both are undefined and [] is also undefined?